# How do you set a minimum and maximum date in Python to validate against input?

Tags: python, date, datetime, range

Question in the title. I'm writing a program to ask the user to input a date in the mm/dd/yy format, validate that date if it is only in the year 2013, and then print the date in this format: July 01, 2013. I'm just getting a logic error in that the program will still print the date even if the year is not 2013. Here is my code:

```
import datetime


def main():
    def date_method(user_date):
        date_list = user_date.split('/')
        month = int(date_list[0])
        day = int(date_list[1])
        year = 2000 + int(date_list[2])
        try:
            datetime.datetime.min = 1/1/2013
            datetime.datetime.max = 12/31/2013
            the_date = datetime.date(month, day, year)
            correct_date = "True"
            return the_date, correct_date
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
            the_date = 1/1/1
            correct_date = "False"
            return the_date, correct_date

    correct_date = "False"
    while correct_date == "False":
        user_date = str(input("Please enter a date in the month/day/year format: mm/dd/yy. "))
        the_date, correct_date = date_method(user_date)
        if correct_date == "True":
            print("Date: ", datetime.date.strftime(the_date, "%B %d, %y"))

main()
```

Where I think I am off is my datetime.datetime.min and datetime.datetime.max variables.

Comment: have you tried adding an if/else statement for the year variable? It seems simpler that way.

Comment: You realise `/` is used for division?

Comment: Yes, I now realize that. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python **built-in types** are **immutable** so you cannot set any attributes, if you want to verify the year just convert to a datetime object and check the `.year` attribute is `>= 13`.

```
if mn_year <= dt.year <= mx_year
```

Even if you could `1/1/2013`  is an equation not a date.

Something like the following:

```
user_date = input("Please enter a date in the month/day/year format: mm/dd/yy. ")

def date_method(user_date):
    try:
        mn, dy, year = user_date.split('/')
        the_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("{} {} {}".format(mn, dy, year), "%d %m %y")
        if the_date.year >= 2013:
            correct_date = "True"
            return the_date.year, correct_date
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
        ....
```

If you want a min and max use the mn_year and mx_year as above. You don't need to cast to ints, you can use datetime.strptime as above using the strings. You also don't need to cast input to a str, that is exactly what it is. Splitting and unpacking the `user_date` string in the try will also catch when a user enters incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `datetime.datetime.min` and `datetime.datetime.max` smells like global variables to me. A better solution would be to simply check if it's in a range.

```
import datetime

def date_method(user_date):
    date_list = user_date.split('/')
    month = int(date_list[0])
    day = int(date_list[1])
    year = 2000 + int(date_list[2])
    the_date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    if datetime.date(2013, 1, 1) <= the_date <= datetime.date(2013, 12, 31):
        return the_date, True
    else:
        print("Date entered is not in the year 2013.")
        return datetime.date(1, 1, 1), False

def main():
    correct_date = False
    while correct_date == False:
        user_date = input("Please enter a date in the month/day/year format: mm/dd/yy. ")
        the_date, correct_date = date_method(user_date)
        if correct_date:
            print("Date: ", datetime.date.strftime(the_date, "%B %d, %y"))

main()
```

Some more faults in your code:

- You use the strings `"True"` and `"False"` instead of just `True` and `False`.
- It's `datetime.date(year, month, day)` instead of `datetime.date(month, day, year)`
- Why would you define `date_method` inside `main()` ?
- The operator `/` can't be used for dates like in your example. What you are really doing is simply dividing a number, and Python parses that number as a date. (Which is nothing like the date you meant)

Comment: I understand now. One reason I wanted to keep the try/exception clause is so that I could print the ValueError exception telling the user what is specifically wrong with their input. How would I go about being able to print out a error message if the year value is not 2013? I know I would use an if statement in the except clause, but I don't know how I would go about accessing then year value from the user_date variable.

Comment: I edited my answer, is this what you're after? I only added a simple `print` statement in the else part.